# When are you charged for resetting your IP?

Tags: hacker-experience

When visiting the ISP, you can reset your IP for free, or, if you did that recently, pay money. The option to pay does not appear unless you have the specified amount of money in your accounts. If you have the specified amount or more, you can pay to reset your IP. This usually takes about 10 minutes (for me), unless you are running other processes, and during that time some things may happen to your money.

If you are charged before the process starts, this wouldn't be a problem. However if you are charged after the process ends, you might not have the needed amount of money.

**Are you charged before or after the IP reset process runs?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're charged after the process completes.**

Source: Personal experience.

If you have the required amount of money, you can start the reset process. While the process is running it doesn't matter how much money you have in your bank accounts, but one it finishes you will be charged. If you do not have the necessary money, the process is deleted and you will need to start over again.